# oracle.sql.CLOB cannot be cast to oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, datasource

This is my java code.
I am using wildfly 10.0.0 and java 1.8 and oracle 12c.

```
   public void getCellValue(){         
            PreparedStatement pstat = getConnection().prepareStatement("select empty_clob() from dual");
            resultSet = pstat.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            DatumWithConnection datum = (DatumWithConnection) resultSet.getClob(1);
            OracleConnection oconn = datum.getOracleConnection();
   }

 public Connection getConnection()
 {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    this.mDataSource = ((DataSource)ic.lookup(lookupName));
    this.mConnection = this.mDataSource.getConnection();
    return this.mConnection;
 }
```

when I call the function getCellValue, I get the such error.

> ```
> 22:18:56,622 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.CLOB cannot be cast to
> ```
>
> oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection

How can I fix this error?
Thank you for viewing.

Comment: ihmo this is non-sense. `select empty_clob() from dual`. Such a LOB is invalid and there is no way how you cloud write into it.

Comment: In fact Oracle does not return a LOB, but LOB locator. It is something like file-handle and it is associated with some storage(segment). The storage can be either a LOB column in a table - or temporary tablespace (when calling dbms_lob.create_temporary or Connection.createLob()). Your LOB is nether of those.

Comment: thank you for commenting. this is valid. I was using so.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You create an empty CLOB via an existing Oracle Database connection that you then want to cast to a `DatumWithConnection` to get another database connection from?

Comment: I am going to get OracleConnection from jdbcconnection.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
public class MyTest
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
                MyTest test1 = new MyTest();
                oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection conn = test1.getConnection();
                test1. getCellvalue(conn);
        }

        private void getCellvalue(Connection dbConnection) throws SQLException {        
                PreparedStatement pstat = dbConnection.prepareStatement("select empty_clob() from dual");
                ResultSet resultSet = pstat.executeQuery();
                resultSet.next();
                DatumWithConnection datum = (DatumWithConnection) resultSet.getClob(1);
                OracleConnection oconn = datum.getOracleConnection()
        }

        private oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection getConnection() throws SQLException {
                    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service_name”;
                    OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
                    Properties prop = new Properties();
                    prop.setProperty("user","scott");
                    prop.setProperty("password","tiger");
                    ds.setConnectionProperties(prop);
                    ds.setURL(url);
                    oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection conn =
                    (oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection)ds.getConnection();
                    return conn;

        }
}
```

Perhaps use resultSet.getCLOB instead of resultSet.getClob.